# why is parsing different in this bash for loop example

Tags: bash

Why are the fields parsed differently in these two cases:

1. ```
   for u in $( echo "a b c"); do echo $u; done
   a
   b
   c
   ```
2. ```
   for u in "a b c"; do echo $u; done
   a b c
   ```

In the second case, I'm used to this. I can change IFS to get this to parse fields by whitespace. But in the first case, why does it work to parse by whitespace?

Comment: The result of the command substitution undergoes word splitting because there is no quotes to prevent it. `for u in "$(echo a b c)"; do echo $u; done` would give the same result as the second case.

Comment: Great, thanks. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

The unquoted command substitution undergoes word-splitting, the same as if you had used

```
fake_list=$(echo "a b c")
for u in $fake_list; do echo $u; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This extra `double quotes` around `$(echo "a b c")` would prevent the word splitting:

```
 for u in "$(echo "a b c")"; do echo $u; done
```

Output

```
a b c
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever Command Substitution is involved, word splitting may occur twice, once inside the command substitution, and once outside.  Quotes will prevent word splitting for either, but you need to quote the command substitution to prevent the result from being split in this case.

Three examples:

```
set -- "a b c"
echo $#
1
```

Word splitting is prevented by the quotes in this case.

```
set -- $(echo "a b c")
echo $#
3
```

In the second case, `$(...)` is replaced by `a b c`
But now, this is not quoted anymore, so it is once again subject to 
word splitting.

If we move the quotes to outside of the command substitution, the result
of `echo` is once again interpreted as a single entry:

```
set -- "$(echo a b c)"
echo $#
```

1

This could also be written as

```
set -- "$(echo "a b c")"
echo $#
```

1

In either case, it's the outer quotes that prevent the outer word split.
Whether word splitting is done inside is not relevant here.

Comment: Consider `$(echo \"a b c\")`; that doesn't "get rid of the quotes".

Comment: @melpomene I did not see backslashes in the original, so I don't see how this is relevant.

Comment: It's a counterexample to your explanation. `echo \"a b c\"` outputs `"a b c"` (including the quotes), but it still gets split into 3 parts. So your explanation can't be right.

Comment: Not for the case used in the original question. If the OP had trouble with different levels of quoting I would address this.